# Classes com o atributos e métodos static que cria a si próprio

Tags: c++

Olá, hoje na empresa que eu trabalho vi uma forma diferente de criar um objeto, perguntei o por que? E me responderam que o padrão da empresa é não usar objetos estáticos, achei interessante. Tentei reproduzir o código em casa para testar, porém não estou conseguindo, não me lembro direito como ele estava. Daí me veio duas perguntas: Qual a usabilidade disso além de uma classe de configuração? O que eu devo fazer para compilar corretamente?
(Erros de compilação seguido dos códigos).

`Error: Undefined reference to 'Base::_obj'`

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{

public:
    static Base* _obj;

    Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Fui criado!\n";
    }

    void falar()
    {
        std::cout << "Alô\n";
    }

    static Base* getBase()
    {
        if(!_obj)
        {
            _obj = new Base();
        }

        return _obj;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Base::getBase()->falar();

    return 0;

}
```

--Edit--

Eu vi no meu trabalho, e este abaixo é mais ou menos como é o código, vendo também aquele link que o usuário aviana comentou abaixo, porém continua aparecendo um erro na compilação, não sei se preciso passar um parâmetro na hora de compilar. (erro seguido do código).

`o.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Base7getBaseEv[__ZN4Base7getBaseEv]+0x2d)||undefined reference to 'Base::_obj'`

```
//https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton
//-fpermissive flag activated
#include <iostream>


class Base{

private:
    static Base* _obj;

    Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Fui criado!\n";
    }

public:

    void falar()
    {
        std::cout << "Alô\n";
    }

    static Base* getBase()
    {
        if(!_obj)
            _obj = new Base;

        return _obj;
    }
};

Base* _obj = nullptr;

int main()
{

    Base* b = Base::getBase();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: O código que vc viu se assemelha a esse padrão? https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton#Em_C++

Comment: isso, mais ou menos, anotei ele hoje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver! Notei que a edição que eu fiz, não setei de forma correta o ponteiro estático em nulo, segue o código atualizado, agora compilando:

```
//https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton
//-fpermissive flag activated
//https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/482918
#include <iostream>

class Base{

private:
    //meu objeto único estático
    static Base* _obj;

    //construtor em private para que não seja possível acessar de fora da classe
    Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Fui criado!\n";
    }

public:

    //teste
    void falar()
    {
        std::cout << "Alo\n";
    }

    //getHandle retorna o _obj se estiver instanciado
    //se não, inicia o objeto
    static Base* getBase()
    {
        if(!_obj)
            _obj = new Base;

        return _obj;
    }
};

//inicializa como nullptr
Base* Base::_obj = nullptr;

int main()
{
    //mãos a obra!
    Base::getBase()->falar();

    return 0;

}
```